# Mechanism of apple in-app Purchase need a restored button?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

After reading Apple's terms with my average English I understand that all application who sell non-consumable item need to use the IAP and insert a "restored button" if not the application is rejected by apple.

My user need to be connected to an account to play in my game and the IAP is attached to his account. And the non-consumable item is a money that he can spend. So I can't add a "restore button"...

So my question is, compared to my project do I really have to install a restore button? And if yes, how?

### Update

I found my answer :

[image]

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2)

So I don't need a restored button because I've sell **consumable** item.

Comment: You should read the [In-App Purchasing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1).

Comment: Your IAP sounds like a consumable, not a non-consumable. *money that they can spend*

Comment: Please don’t put an answer in the question. If you think you can give an answer to your own question, write it as an Answer, not as part of the Question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to look, how other similar apps work.

Add a restore button somewhere in settings. User taps the restore button.

1. If user is logged in, then his balance is automatically restored from the account on your server and you just tell him, that his balance is restored.
2. If he is not logged in, you should tell him, that he should login to restore his balance and then show him a login view.

All this should be reproducable by AppStore's app tester.

Comment: Thanks to your reply. Ok I anderstand but for access to my app the user need to be connected, so he will always have his monney, so I do not need to put a restore button I think.

Comment: You need to put it anyway although it is senseless.

Comment: Put it to display a notification to say "
To find your currency you have to connect to the account with which you have made your purchase"...